# SharePoint 2010 Foundation - Workflow errors out after task overdue. What could be the cause?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

Yes, it's SharePoint 2010 Foundation. We have a workflow that runs sequentially. For each step, we have an approver and a task overdue every 24 hours. This will send a reminder email out. This works most of the time. Sometimes, after the task overdue, the workflow will error out. No logs.

[Workflow Error Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSpzy.png)

Reproducing the problem is already a headache because it doesn't always happen. We've added logs everywhere but whenever the problem happens, no logs are shown. It's like the error happens when it's in the timer job and it's not throwing it back to our code.

We tried updating to the latest patch. We tried clearing the timer job cache.

I know this will be a tough one to solve directly with so few details. But, any directions we can pursue?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: New information as requested by Mike.

[Overall Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUttD.png)

In the middle, there are 3 pieces

- TaskChangedSequence
- SendReminderSequence (this is where the problem happens)
- LateSubmissionSequence

[Three conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlOZa.png)

Right now it seems like it's dying after 'DelayUntilTaskOverDue' in SendReminderSequence. We don't get the overdue email. We tried logging in sendEmailTaskOverDue_ExecuteCode and it doesn't get there.

Comment: Can you also post an image of the workflow?

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the delayed response, and thanks for looking into this. I've edited the post to include images of the workflow. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike, just wanted to see if the images I posted of our workflow make any sense to you? Let me know if you have any questions to help further troubleshoot this problem. Thanks!